# Need a word for "Unravel in the worst possible way"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am writing something in a blog and I want to write this sentence

> Its a very hard thing to follow a path you believe in and are
>   passionate about when everything around you starts to _________ and
>   every tom dick and harry you know takes the other lucrative path

I want to fill up the blank with something that means "unravel in the worst possible way", i.e. things starting to crumble around you, but you are alone and strongwilled on that path. Any such words/phrases in English? I don't want to just use the word crumble - it's too negative and it stands out too much. *Unravel in a bad way* softens the blow a little bit, but just *unravel* on its own is too subtle.

Comment: but *unravel* isn't subtle. It's the word I would expect to [fill in the blank](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22starts+to+unravel%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) and wouldn't need any additional adjective to understand falling apart being bad.

Comment: Yeah, the trouble is, you're trying to say two different things with one word. You speak of faith and passion, but then you're telling us that the problem is: Tom, Dick, and Harry are making more money than you. Doesn't matter which word you pick - it's not a cohesive statement.

Comment: taking your title a bit too literally. "[Capsize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot#Capsizing)" is one possibility.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I like the word *disintegrate* for your sentence. (Although I don't know that it's any less "negative" than *crumble.*)

[Wordnick offers these definitions:](https://www.wordnik.com/words/disintegrate)

> To become reduced to components, fragments, or particles
>
> To undo the integrity of, break into parts
>
> To separate into component parts; reduce to fragments; break up or destroy the cohesion of

(Note: Be careful about a run-on sentence.)

Comment: I really like disintegrate :)

Answer (score 14):

You could follow Yeats and go with "[fall apart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Second_Coming_%28poem%29)":

> **Things fall apart**; the centre cannot hold; 
>   Mere anarchy is loosed upon the world

Comment: @Slartibartfast, no problem. :) Your question also made my think of the first verse of Kipling's "[If](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/175772)": "If you can keep your head when all about you   /
    Are losing theirs and blaming it on you,   /
If you can trust yourself when all men doubt you, /
    But make allowance for their doubting too;   "

Comment: In a similar vein, "come undone"

Comment: @AE, or the bastardised version: "If you can keep your head when all about you are losing theirs, then you do not fully understand the severity of the situation" ;)

Answer (score 5):

*Devolve.*

*Degenerate*

Though there are definitely negative connotations here.  Alternatively, just stick with *Unravel*.  It's succinct, and less negative than alternatives.

Comment: Yeah I considered that, but Unravel is probably too subtle on its own

Answer (score 5):

*Collapse*

or

*Go to shit*, but that might be too negative too ;)

The soul of wit is brevity.  You might shorten your sentiment a bit, maybe something like:

> *The road of passion is brutal when things fall apart--while every tom, dick and harry ride the road to wealth.*

Answer (score 4):

This may also be too negative for your taste, but consider *[implode](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/implode)*

> to break down or fall apart from within :  self-destruct *Merriam-Webster*

Answer (score 1):

Two good phrases for what you describe:

> when everything around you starts to [**come undone**] ...

and,

> when everything around you starts to [**go to pieces**] ...

Answer (score 1):

Disassemble - which, although it has a strong mechanical or technical sense to it,  might be appropriate for a situation where one has worked long and hard (and passionately) to achieve a goal, construct an environment, or build a complex fragile alliance among individuals, that unexpectedly begins to disassemble - in a manner (and often at a fast rate/speed) which one cannot stop - but one can only helplessly - watch. And there is usually no one remaining to "mourn" when the dust finally settles except the one who invested the most.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be [*discombobulate*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discombobulate):

> To throw into a state of confusion; to befuddle or perplex.

Comment: I'm not sure that 'things' (circumstances) can be discombobulated - my impression is that it's only people who can be. If things do fall apart then of course that could cause people to be discombobulated.

Answer (score 1):

"discorporate"

> v. (transitive), to deprive (a corporate body) of corporation

"Unbind your mind, there is no time, boin-n-n-n-n-n-g, to lick your stamps, and paste them in, discorporate, and we’ll begin" - Frank Zappa

Answer (score -1):

"recalcitrate" from Latin recalcitratus.

1

:  to kick back

2

:  to protest or resist vigorously :  show stubborn opposition

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE]. 
We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Can you edit your post to explain how it answers the question, and add references to substantiate it?